# Stack level too deep with compass-rails, sass-rails and susy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, compass-sass, sprockets, susy-compass

I'm getting slightly frustrated with this error that I can't seem to figure out. I used to have a html.erb file that used a css-file, but now I switched to scss and added sass-rails, compass-rails and susy. It generates this error when I try to load the same page.

The error:

> Showing [..]/app/views/layouts/shared.html.erb where line # raised:
>
> stack level too deep
>
> > (in [..]/app/assets/stylesheets/sharepage_new/screen.css.scss)

From terminal:

> ActionView::Template::Error (stack level too deep 
>   (in [..]/app/assets/stylesheets/sharepage_new/screen.css.scss)):
>     sprockets (2.1.3) lib/sprockets/context.rb:180
>
> Rendered /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms)
>     Rendered /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (0.7ms)
>    Rendered /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (3.5ms)

From Gemfile:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'compass-rails', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'susy', git: "git://github.com/ericam/susy.git"
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that a indention error? Should not be an issue with scss tho..